# Burned DVD/CD from yesterday are blank!

Tags: iso, dvd, burning

I just burned a Windows **.iso** image to a blank DVD. And now it just says blank media, when I read from Ubuntu!

Is it a problem with the .iso image, or because it is a Windows .iso image?

*Very troublesome for me.* I'm using *Brasero* Disc Burner.

Comment: why don't you use a USB instead?

Comment: This happens to me as well on Windows and Linux. Nothing you can do then be diligent in your burning.

Comment: also happened to me, tried to burn using k3b, brasero with 4x speed. wasted two DVDs.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this happen to me before. The data has clearly been written to the disk if you hold it to the light but for some reason it registers as a blank disk.

Solution:

Toss it in the garbage and try again with another disk. Also, try changing the burn speed; some people say that you are prone to less errors if you burn the disk at a low speed.

Answer (score 0):

Burn it using Ubuntu.
The process is really simple: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu.
If the problem persisted, it might be a hardware problem.

Comment: But i just burned it yesterday and today it shows as blank cd.If i write it again, doesn't that mean that i'm burning it twice?Probably a software problem.

Comment: If it is still blank, then you can still write on it. I am just suggesting that you burn it using Ubuntu (trying a different environment) to know exactly if it is a hardware or a software issue.

Comment: Just burned it right away and reboot,still says blank cd.

Comment: I am afraid that your hardware is no longer working well.

Answer (score 0):

### **Background:**

This is a common issue under Windows, with the default behaviour being to create 'the intent' of burning the data (but not actually encoding).

This can also be caused by drive (hardware) issues; wherein the data is written, but the CD/DVD is not correctly encoded to mark written/unused space (and later appears as still unused/blank).

---

### **You need to be more specific:**

**Are you trying to create an *Ubuntu LiveCD?***

You likely can't, as Ubuntu (desktop) will NOT fit on a 600MB CD);

**OR, just experiencing an issue with writing an .iso file to optical media?**

Comment: I'm actually trying to burn a windows .iso image.

Comment: Not trying to make live linux cd, just windows installation cd.I have a cd that is 4,7GB big.

Comment: Better known as a **DVD** (not a CD).

Comment: Yeah,i'm using a DVD.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen when burning something stored on a network share. Brasero goes thru the process of burning the disk, but it's blank afterwards. I had to copy the files to the local drive, then burn them.